# Mongoose promise arguments passing issue

Tags: mongoose, promise

I try to use a chained promise construct to seed my mongodb database.

### Non working code

```
var p = new mongoose.Promise();
p
  .then(function() {
    //remove all categories
    return Category.remove({}).exec();
  })
  .then(function() {
    //remove all competitors
    return Competitor.remove({}).exec();
  })
  .then(function() {
    //add categories
    return Category.create({
      name: 'cat1',
      info: 'Category #1'
    }, {
      name: 'cat2',
      info: 'Category #2'
    });
  })
  .then(function(cat1, cat2) {
    //add competitors
    return Competitor.create([{
      first_name: 'Titi',
      last_name: 'Tito',
      _category: cat1._id
    }, {
      first_name: 'Tata',
      last_name: 'Tato',
      _category: cat2._id
    }]);
  })
  .then(function() {
    console.log('finished populating models');
  })
  .end(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

I get an error saying cat2 is undefined.

### Working code

If i do this, it works but I don't understand why

```
var p = new mongoose.Promise();
p
  .then(function() {
    //remove all categories
    return Category.remove({}).exec();
  })
  .then(function() {
    //remove all competitors
    return Competitor.remove({}).exec();
  })
  .then(function() {
    //add categories
    return Category.create({
      name: 'cat1',
      info: 'Category #1'
    }, {
      name: 'cat2',
      info: 'Category #2'
    })
    .then(function(cat1, cat2) {
      //add competitors
      return Competitor.create([{
        first_name: 'Titi',
        last_name: 'Tito',
        _category: cat1._id
      }, {
        first_name: 'Tata',
        last_name: 'Tato',
        _category: cat2._id
      }]);
    });
  })
  .then(function() {
    console.log('finished populating models');
  })
  .end(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
p.fulfill();
```

Does somebody know what's wront woth the first code ?

Comment: `then` always has a single fulfillment argument.

Answer (score 0):

It can only be that `Category.create` returns an odd kind of promise, whose `.then()` takes a success function that receives two (or more) parameters - much like a jQuery `.then()`.

In the non-working version, `.then()` is chained indirectly such that the outer mongoose promise chain is fed the odd-promise resolved with its two parameters. And mongoose's `.then()` is only partially successful in handling this situation - the callback is passed one param not two, so throws an error on reaching the line `_category: cat2._id`.

In the working version, this is not an issue because `.then()` is chained directly, forming an inner odd-promise chain, the second part of which picks up both of the first part's params. In this case, the outer mongoose promise chain continues without error because, although it is (in all likelihood) also fed with an odd-promise resolved with two params, it doesn't attempt to operate on either of them.

If my analysis is correct, then you should be able to make the non-working pattern work by "unspreading" the odd-promise's multiple params as follows :

```
function unspread() {
    return Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments);
}

var p = new mongoose.Promise();

p.then(function() {
    return Category.remove({}).exec();//remove all categories
}).then(function() {
    return Competitor.remove({}).exec();//remove all competitors
}).then(function() {
    //add categories
    return Category.create({
        name: 'cat1',
        info: 'Category #1'
    }, {
        name: 'cat2',
        info: 'Category #2'
    }).then(unspread);
}).then(function(arrayOfParams) {
    //add competitors
    return Competitor.create([{
        first_name: 'Titi',
        last_name: 'Tito',
        _category: arrayOfParams[0]._id
    }, {
        first_name: 'Tata',
        last_name: 'Tato',
        _category: arrayOfParams[1]._id
    }]);
}).then(function() {
    console.log('finished populating models');
}).end(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});

p.fulfill();
```

I'm not suggesting that this is a better solution than your working version but maybe (if it works) it's a trick you can keep up your sleeve for another occasion.